# CollectionView insde TableViewCell not working correctly in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, autolayout

I'm developing app which contains UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell.
But what happens is that collection view's cell auto width is not working correctly when reloading data.
Here's a screenshot.
[image]

Here's a code.

```
@IBOutlet weak var cv_inside: UICollectionView!
...
cv_inside.collectionViewLayout = AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout(horizontalAlignment: .left, verticalAlignment: .top)

if let flowlayout = cv_inside.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    flowlayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 25)
    flowlayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
}
cv_inside.isScrollEnabled = false
cv_inside.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
....
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    cv_inside.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    heightOfCollectionViewConstant.constant = cv_inside.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.updateConstraints()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

It worked fine before iOS 12 and I researched that I have to add this code.

```
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let leftConstraint = contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor)
    let rightConstraint = contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor)
    let topConstraint = contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor)
    let bottomConstraint = contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leftConstraint, rightConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint])
```

But even I added this code, it doesn't work.
Can anyone please help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line :

```
flowlayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 25)
```

you should also set cellSize in Interface [image]Builder like this:

Comment: i tried with that way and ui looks bad, sorry but can you please tell me how can i define height to 25?

Comment: It looks like this. https://imgur.com/a/p9r54xN   can you please tell me how to look like previous version?

Comment: are you using a storyboard ?

Comment: did you set a cellSize in your collectionView ?

Comment: sorry but how to do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187322/discussion-between-zhengge-che-and-mosbah).